# huawei devices are not loading the google maps inside my app

Tags: google-maps-api-3, huawei-developers, appgallery

I am trying to upload my app to the huawei's app gallery but every time I upload it for a review they send a vid where the map inside the app is not loading, At first i thought the issue was that they might be testing it using a device that doesn't have GMS but even after that, the map is not loading

what I tried so far
-I added the signing-certificate fingerprint to the google cloud

but i then remembered that Huawei makes you sign the app with another signing certificate which is SHA-256 and the google console can only take SHA-1 how can i fix this issue
[image: huawei's signing certificate]

Comment: hi@Mohmmad Qunibi, Just to confirm your question，about *Huawei makes you sign the app with another signing certificate which is SHA-256* could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @shirley yeah sure i will add a screenshot for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was as expected since Huawei uses the app signing certificate that they created, it wouldn't load the map because google can't take SHA-256, so to fix the issue you should use APK instead of AAB to be able to use your app signing certificate to let the app be able to communicate with the API.

that means you can only use AAB when the app uses HMS instead of GMS

Answer (score 1):

First you are advised to use [Huawei map kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-MapKit?ha_source=hms1) on huawei phones.

With respect to your second question, you could use the following command to to obtain SHA1 and SHA256 of the same key:

`keytool -list -v -keystore android.jks`

[image]

Comment: i have already added that SHA to google, but only some huawei devices with GMS are not rendering google maps

Comment: Is there GMS in your huawei test device?

Comment: It has GMS and it worked with google maps (mate 20 pro), it was downloaded from google play, but when huawei do the testing, it won't so i thought it might be the signing certificate that huawei gives you

Comment: and about the huawei map kit, i am going to use later, but for now i hid the maps for the phones with no GMS